# jquery animate bug, only in google chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, jquery-animate

Oviously my code is working fine in all browsers including Ie just google crome makes a problem.

I am using the jquery .animate function to create some kind of slide show... When I hit the left button, the box containing images slides right, when I hit the right button the box slides left...

To the issue, only on crome the animation leeks extremely in performance and the end position of the animation is not correct, animation to the right side leads to abnormal jumps... I have no clue what crome is doing there...

I tested the issue on 2 different computers and its the same, a friend of mine told me that he has not got the animation problem on his chrome...

Here is a code example:

```
$('#stpa_arrow_left').bind({
    click: function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $('#stpa_imgBoardBox').children().animate({"left": "+=186px"}, "slow", function() {
            $(this).stop(true);
        }); 
    }
});

$('#stpa_arrow_right').bind({
    click: function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $('#stpa_imgBoardBox').children().animate({"left": "-=186px"}, "slow", function() {
            $(this).stop(true);
        });
    }
});
```

And here is a live example (still unfinished project i am working on) - Its the center box with the left and right arrow... www.united-travellers.at/pre-login/index.php

Comment: WFM on Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2

What version are you testing with? What exactly are you doing? Can you isolate the problem as a js fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

you just take the latest jquery. This bug has already been fixed.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the bug fix?